# how to get gridid in iframe using extjs

Tags: asp.net, extjs

I have a page 1.aspx contans a grid extjs. in page 2.aspx i using function ext.window to call page 1.aspx, and then how to do i get id grid in iframe page 1,.aspx.

example
Page 2 when i call it

```
var win = new Ext.Window({
                    title: ''
                      , width: 700
                      , height: 500
                      , plain: true,
                    html: String.format('<iframe id="report" frameborder="0" src="1.aspx" width="100%" height="100%" />'),
                    listeners: {

                        close: function () {
                            debugger;
                            var q = $("#report").contents().find("#grid");
                        }
                    }
                });
                win.show();
                win.center();
```

in the page 1 include grid

Thanks all for help

Answer (score 0):

Store the grid object in your page 1.aspx in a global variable i.e.

```
window.myGrid = yourGrid;
```

Then you can access your grid from your page 2.aspx like that:

```
var myGrid = document.getElementById('report').contentWindow.myGrid;
```

(This only works if the iframe and the page from where you are accessing it are in the same domain).